# How to recover my password from my file.key

Tags: passwords, gnupg, pgp, file-encryption, gpg4win

I don't remember my passphrase for my PGP key that was created several years ago.

**How can I decrypt my file.key to recover it?
Or what should I do to recover it from my file.key?**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community. What's your goal?